# String.Format in conjunction with CultureInfo C#

Tags: c#, cultureinfo, string.format

I want to format a price using string.Format. I am able to get the correct currency symbol but can't figure out the regex to always have 2 decimal places regardless if they are 0s. Here is my code:

```
 CultureInfo us = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
 price.text = string.Format(us, "{0:C}",inventory.priceTotal);
```

Comment: [Your code works fine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Cn3sfq), the issue must be something/somewhere else.

Comment: Best guess is that your `inventory.priceTotal` field is not a numeric type. If it is not a numeric type (such as a string), the `string.Format()` operation will have no effect on it.

Answer (score 6):

Add `2` to `C` so `C2`

```
string.Format(us, "{0:C2}",inventory.priceTotal);
```

See also [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Still only displays 1 decimal place when a decimal is 0, unless the dollar value is 1 digit. So $9.90 will work as intended but $10.10 will display as $10.1

Comment: @LewisSeddon - I cant reproduce that: `Console.WriteLine(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:C2}", 10.1));` produces string `"$10.10"`

Comment: You don't need to specify `C2`, just `C` is enough. OPs code already works fine.

Comment: @DavidG - that assumes that US culture is always used, the number of default decimal places is dependent on the selected culture supplied in the format call. See [Default precision specifier: Defined by NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyDecimalDigits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencydecimaldigits(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yes, and the `en-US` culture will always have a value of 2.

Comment: @DavidG - right, I just stated that. The (my) assumption is that it is not always culture code `en-US` and you still want to display 2 decimal places.

Comment: @LewisSeddon That is not proof that your code posted above doesn't work, it's proof that *something* in your code is wrong. Your assumption here is not correct.

Comment: @LewisSeddon For example: The label holding the text isn't long enough so truncates the last character off, or something else in your code truncates it to 5 characters, or `inventory.priceTotal` is a string instead of a numeric type.

Answer (score 0):

Think my inventory code is a mess. I have strings being parsed to doubles and then passing those to the .text via .ToString(). I think I will separate the digits from the symbol and just dynamically set the symbol independently.